# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLoggerFactory

Tags: android

I am using this lib     compile 'com.danikula:videocache:2.7.0' from [github](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache)

to cache videos , everything was running fine until today ,  I just suddenly start getting this error , I have changed nothing to get this error ?

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLoggerFactory
                                                                               at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:86)
                                                                               at com.danikula.videocache.StorageUtils.<clinit>(StorageUtils.java:23)
                                                                               at com.danikula.videocache.HttpProxyCacheServer$Builder.<init>(HttpProxyCacheServer.java:356)
                                                                               at com.network.imyth.network.global_functions.newProxy(global_functions.java:377)
                                                                               at com.network.imyth.network.global_functions.getProxy(global_functions.java:372)
                                                                               at com.network.imyth.network.MainWindow_page_1$RecyclerAdapter$NewPostHolder.<init>(MainWindow_page_1.java:855)
                                                                               at com.network.imyth.network.MainWindow_page_1$RecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainWindow_page_1.java:1309)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6367)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5555)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14840)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:636)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14840)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1697)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1551)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1460)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14840)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1795)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14840)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14840)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14840)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14840)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1697)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1551)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1460)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14840)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14840)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1697
```

> dependencies {
>       compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21' }

Comment: check your libraries

Comment: dude i changed nothing in the libs ,,

Answer (score 0):

Here your project is searching the class `SubstituteLoggerFactory` but it's not available.

Follow

1. Download the library of `slf4j` from [download here](https://www.slf4j.org/dist/slf4j-1.7.25.zip) and copy the required jar file into the lib folder.
2. Right click on the jar > choose `add as library`
3. `Clean` and `Rebuild` the project.

Comment: will i download the zip and extract it but there's a ton of jar files in it which one should i copy ?

Comment: From those, copy  **slf4j-api-1.7.25** , then let me know. You can check by searching the class name in the folder, because all source codes are also added in that zip.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/slf4j/impl/AndroidLoggerAdapter.class

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.21'
    compile files('C:/Users/iMyth/Desktop/Network/app/src/libs/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar')
}

Comment: delete `slf4j-api‌​-1.7.21.jar` from the project and `build.gradle` too. Then add the latest one.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile files('C:/Users/iMyth/Desktop/Network/app/src/libs/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar')
}

Comment: still same error i check the Class name it exists in slf4j-api‌​-1.7.25 ,, but for some wired reason i still get the same error

Comment: Can u add your `build.gradle` here?

Comment: the video catch lib build.gradle >>>

Comment: the main app build.gradle >>>

Comment: Yes it is _____

Comment: Copy that jar in the **libs** which is under the _app_ , in between _build_ & _src_ , not in other folder.

Comment: Your `compile of jar` statement should be in the **app** `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Here where i added the jar file

Comment: Your jar seems inside the `src`, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: One question-- This `libs` folder was already there or you've created?

Comment: where it shuld be i dont get it ?

Comment: i think i created it ,im not sure

Comment: i will try and move the libs folder to app root dir

Comment: Use latest version of **AS** , the `libs` dir should be automatically created. after adding the jar as a library, add `compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar')` in _app_ `build.gradle`. Rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

it a problem with the library i just loaded an older version all shit back to normal